# Using express-session variable as type array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am creating an e-commerce type site with shopping cart functionality.

When a Customer adds product to cart, I need to add the data of the product into an array in the session variable.

I tried like this:

```
 router.post('/addtocart', authCheck.login, async(req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body)

    req.session.cart = []
    
    let doc = {
        ...req.body
    }
    await req.session.cart.push(doc)
    console.log(req.session.cart)
```

What happens is each time a product is added to the cart, it doesn't keep the existing data in there. So if I go to add two products, only the latest one shows in there. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are creating a new array every time

Comment: @KonradLinkowski how would I fix that?

Comment: You've shown to little code to know, please add some more

Comment: @KonradLinkowski just added some more. Not to much code

Comment: With `req.session.cart = req.session.cart || []`, you would initialize the cart only if it does not yet exist in the session.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen that didn't seem to work. Just overwrites it still

Comment: `await` does nothing here btw, `push` doesn't return a promise

Comment: Replacing `req.session.cart = []` with `req.session.cart ??= []` fixes the issue for me, and @HeikoTheißen solution works as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain your problem: the `req.session.cart = []` code is emptying your `req.session.cart` data by passing it a value of empty array `= []` every time your `/addtocart` endpoint is triggered.

A solution would be:

```
router.post('/addtocart', authCheck.login, async(req, res) => {

    // req.session.cart = []
    let updatedCart = []
    let { cart } = req.session
    
    let doc = {
     ...req.body
     }
    // await req.session.cart.push(doc) //await is unnecessary here
    updatedCart.push(...cart, doc)
    req.session.cart = updatedCart
    console.log("req.session.cart: ", req.session.cart)
```

You can read more about the `await` keyword at [MDN documentations - await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: You are never saving the `updatedCart` back into the session